# Manual exceptions to indent rule in eslint

Tags: javascript, indentation, lint, eslint

Can the indent rule of `eslint` be brought to overlook a specific line / block opening? A common scenario for me would be something like

```
jQuery(function() {
// long body of code I like to leave at "root" indentation
});
```

But of course `eslint` complains about the missing expected indentation. The following also doesn't give the desired behavior:

```
/* eslint-disable */
jQuery(function() {
/* eslint-enable */
// long body of code I like to leave at "root" indentation
});
```

Any suggestions, besides turning off the indent rule altogether?

Comment: Why do you disable eslint for the first line when the indentation violation occurs on the second line?

Comment: because I was hoping that this way it would not take the first line into consideration for the indenting rule. disabling it on the "long body of code" defeats the purpose of a linter a little bit